# nilpotent elements in a localization of a commutative Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, localization, nilpotence

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $R$ and let $R[S^{-1}]$ be the localization of $R$ at $S$. I want to characterize the nilpotent elements in $R[S^{-1}]$, i.e. the elements $x \in R[S^{-1}]$ such that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x^n = 0$. Is it just the zero element?

My approach is this: let $ x \in R[S^{-1}]$ aka $ x = \frac{a}{b}, a \in R, b \in S$ and let $x$ be nilpotent, aka  $(\frac{a}{b})^n = 0$ for some $n$. But then alls sorts of things can happen in such an abstract setting no?Does it follow that $a^n = 0$? We're not even in an Integral domain... And I know the denominator can have surprising behavior too in this type of construction...

Comment: "Is it just the zero element?" Well, what if you take a ring with a nilpotent element and localize at $S=\{1\}$?

Comment: Hint: we have $(a/b)^n = a^n/b^n$ in $R[S^{-1}]$ by definition of the multiplication. And we have $0 = 0/1$, so this gets us $a^n/b^n = 0/1$ as elements of $R[S^{-1}]$. Do you know when two fractions are equal in $R[S^{-1}]$?

Comment: @MarcPaul Well by construction of fractional equivalence classes, $(a,b) == (c,d)$ iff $ad = bc$. Is that what you're hinting at?

Comment: I guess so. But then it means $a^n=0$ in this case.

Comment: @ghthorpe you have stated the definition of localization in an integral domain, but in an arbitrary (commutative) ring the equivalence relation is $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ if $(ad-bc)s=0$ for some $s \in S$

Comment: @LucyYang so that means nilpotent elements are all the $\frac{a}{b}$,  $a \in R$  $b \in S$ such that $ \exists s \in S, n \in \mathbb{N} $ with $sa^n = 0$ correct?

Comment: @ghthorpe yes, or using some fancier terminology, the radical of the annihilator of $S$